# How long it takes to get the breadcrumbs to show up in Google SERP?

Tags: html, google-search, rich-snippets, breadcrumbs

I have a site that runs since 4 months now with category and products. I put breadcrumbs on my page but I still don't see them in the SERP.

I use the Google breadcrumbs help page to create them.

```html
<ul class="breadcrumbs">
  <li><a href="/" title="">My Page Name</a> <span>&gt; </span></li>
  <li><a href="/category-abc/" title="">Category ABC</a> <span>&gt; </span></li>
  <li>Current Page</li>
</ul>
```

How long will it takes for my breadcrumbs to show up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no definitive timeframe. In fact, there's no guarantee Google will use breadcrumbs in their search results for your pages. As with anything related to Google displaying search results, you can give them clues and express your wishes as for what to display in the search results but ultimately Google will decide if and when it will happen. All you can do is make sure your markup and other signals (http headers, etc) are done correctly. (It also doesn't hurt to increase the link popularity of your pages but that is pretty much true for anything related to Google).

Answer (score -4):

Breadcrumbs do not show up in the SERP results.  Are you confusing breadcrumbs and sitelinks?

Sitelinks are controlled through webmasters tools.

Comment: No, If you google: "SimplePie Documentation: Digg RSS" you will see: **simplepie.org › Documentation › SimplePie ** and NOT a URL.

Comment: -1 This is [absolutely wrong](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=185417)